# QGIS demarcation and parallel line

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, parallel-lines

I have a shapefile which contains a 20 hectare polygon. I want to demarcate 9,48 hectares from the entire polygon with a parallel.

I can make the parallel line with the longer line but I can not do the incision...

Can you help me how to do the incision?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Lassus! Using the **Split Features** tool, you use the _left-mouse button_ to draw the lines and the _right-mouse button_ to split the feature. I'm assuming that's what you meant by _"incision"_? You can find more information from the [QGIS docs](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/topo_editing.html#moderate-ty-tool-split-features).

Comment: Most welcome, glad it worked! I will mark this as a duplicate question as it has been asked and answered before :)